# Change formatting to all paragraphs

Tags: google-apps-script, format, google-docs

I am using script editor to code an something to automatically format my document... What codes should I use for the:

Spacing - Double
Text Background Color - No Background Color (Transparent If Possible)
Text Alignment - Left

I tried the code for text backgroundcolor:

```
var textbackgroundcolor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().asText().setBackgroundColor('#ffffff');
```

I want to change the format from the active document and only the body if possible...

I got the code for spacing to work but I wanted it to change all paragraphs not just the selected ones... Here is the code:

```
var spacing = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs()[1].setLineSpacing(2);
```

I don't want to replace [1] with [0,1,2,3,4,5,6...] because then when there are fewer paragraphs it doesn't work and says it cannot set line spacing for null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script is a full programming language so you have access to features to look at how the document is made up and loops which do repetitive tasks.

Here is a simple example that loops through everything in the document and changes the line spacing for every element that is a paragraph:

```
 var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
 var body = doc.getBody();

 for (var i=0; i<body.getNumChildren(); i++) {
   var child = body.getChild(i);

   if (child.getType() ==  DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {

     child.setLineSpacing(2);
   }
 }
```